# Terraform: rearranging my lists in output file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm writing terraform code to reserve a few ip addresses in each region we work in in google, which I'll later use to assign to a couple of specific instances.

So in my module I have a

```
resource "google_compute_address" "reserved_public_ip" {
}
```

Which iterates over a count and records project, address_type, name, region, subnetwork and address.

So I end up with google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip array.  I can easily make a list of all the names and ip addreses with

```
output "public_reservedip" {
  value = "${zipmap(
    google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip.*.name,
    google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip.*.address
  )}"
}
```

But I can't make a map of region->ipaddress with zipmap using *.region because there are 3 ips per region, so I would only end up with the last ip address, since the region key repeats.

What I am trying to build is an output of the form

```
value = {
   region1 = [list of ips]
   region2 = [list of ips]
   etc...
}
```

So I can feed that to my module that creates the appropriate gcp hosts, and it can grab the list for the region it's currently creating, but I can't figure out the transform that will let me do that.

Example data I have to work with:

```
module.gcp-network.google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip.0:
  id = myproject/northamerica-northeast1/dns-reserve-1-test
  address = 10.128.0.2
  address_type = INTERNAL
  creation_timestamp = 2019-10-08T15:41:08.690-07:00
  description =
  name = dns-reserve-1-test
  network_tier = PREMIUM
  project = myproject
  purpose = GCE_ENDPOINT
  region = northamerica-northeast1
  self_link = https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/northamerica-northeast1/addresses/dns-reserve-1-test
  subnetwork = https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/northamerica-northeast1/subnetworks/test-northamerica-northeast1-public-subnet
  users.# = 0
```

Comment: I should add that we haven't jumped to .12 yet, I'm still using .11, and we can't go to .12 until we vet a fairly large code base.

Comment: so is each `google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip.*.name` a region ? if not, where is the region input?

Comment: *.region is the region... *.name is the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `name` in the earlier examples but then mentioned regions in the final example, so I'm not sure I fully understood what you were trying to achieve here but I'm going to give an example using the `region` attribute which is adaptable to `name` instead if that is what you need:

```
  value = {
    for addr in google_compute_address.reserved_public_ip : addr.region => addr.address...
  }
```

This is a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) projecting your list of objects into a map from region to addresses. The `...` symbol after the `addr.address` expression indicates that you want to *group by* `addr.region`, so the result here will be a map from strings to lists of strings, as you wanted.

This is a Terraform 0.12 feature. There is no equivalent feature in Terraform 0.11.

Comment: FYI, now that we've finally made the jump to TF 12, this answer came in very handy.. I replaced two layers of modules with my original 10 lines of generating code and this three lines of output map.